# Prevent Activity from closing caused by an old finish, when reopened

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I've two activities A and B.
There si a button BTN in A that does:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, B_VIEW);
```

1. I click BTN
2. Then I click back button that perform a finish() in B.
3. Then I quick press the button BTN that opens again B.

The issue is that if the `B.onDestroy()`, caused by the previous `finish()` (step 2), has not yet executed, it executes now, so B closes :-(

I want that, if not yet executed, the B.finish() will not fire if I reopen B. How?

Comment: Something seems wrong, the `finish()` should be individual for each instance of the Activity. Unless Activity B's launch mode is set to be `singleTop`, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off re-working how you handle this kind of process to begin with.

Your best bet is to package the key data into a bundle in the `onSaveInstanceState`, and then checking to see if that bundle exists in the `onCreate(Bundle)` function. Something like this would work [(Largely copied from the Android Docs)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (savedInstanceState==null)
    { //This is the first time starting
        mCurrentScore=0;
        mCurrentLevel=1;
    }
    else
    {
        mCurrentScore=savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel=savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_Level);
    }
}
```